# JQuery Function not returning after call to make table sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run a jquery function to make my table sortable. It gets called, but never returns. Any idea why that could be?

```
function makeTableSortable() {
  alert('mts called');
  //Credit to: http://www.pewpewlaser.com/articles/jquery-tablesorter
  //
  //  Adds sort_header class to ths
  $(".sortable th").addClass("sort_header");

  //  Adds alternating row coloring to table.
  $(".sortable").tablesorter({widgets: ["zebra"]});

  //  Adds "over" class to rows on mouseover
  $(".sortable tr").mouseover(function() {
      $(this).addClass("over");
  });

  //  Removes "over" class from rows on mouseout
  $(".sortable tr").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("over");
  });
  alert('mts done!');
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by not returning

Comment: add `return false;` at the end of function

Comment: What I mean is, the alert 'mts done!' is not being shown.

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there is any error

Comment: try this js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wxUQ6/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be outside of your function :

```
//  Adds "over" class to rows on mouseover
$(".sortable tr").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("over");
});

//  Removes "over" class from rows on mouseout
$(".sortable tr").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("over");
});
```

And complete code look like this:

```
function makeTableSortable() {
alert('mts called');
//Credit to: http://www.pewpewlaser.com/articles/jquery-tablesorter
//
//  Adds sort_header class to ths
$(".sortable th").addClass("sort_header");

//  Adds alternating row coloring to table.
$(".sortable").tablesorter({widgets: ["zebra"]});
alert('mts done!');
}


$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //  Adds "over" class to rows on mouseover
    $(".sortable tr").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("over");
    });

    //  Removes "over" class from rows on mouseout
    $(".sortable tr").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("over");
    });
}
    </script>
```

Something wrong with your :

```
$(".sortable").tablesorter({widgets: ["zebra"]});
```

review your  `tablesorter()`